# find absolute counts for each integer value that occurs in a file

Tags: algorithm

Asked in a recent interview

There is a log file containing one million integers. Each integer is 32 bits in length. Specific integer values in the log file might be repeated. You can read the log file sequentially. You can also read from and write to temp files sequentially; there is no limit to the number of files that may be open at any time. However, you may keep no more than 2000 integers in memory at any given time.

I was asked to produce a histogram showing absolute counts for each integer value that occurs in the log file and state an upper bound on order complexity for the number of times that each integer must be loaded into memory

Comment: I hope the job was a good one I'd have told them to stick it

Answer (score 4):

That's a confusing question. Can't you just read 2,000 numbers, sort them, and then write to a temp file? Do that 500 times and then do an N-way merge. Each number would be loaded into memory twice.

It's the same kind of thing you'd do if you had to sort a terabyte-sized file on a computer that only has 2 gigabytes of RAM.

Comment: @gradbot: True enough, although one would expect that the OS would buffer quite a bit. A 4K buffer will hold half the contents of one of those temporary files. If you can't count on buffering, then it'd probably be better to do the naive merge: write the first buffer, read the next one and merge it with the first to create a new temp file. Read the next buffer and merge, etc. Basically, you're doing 499 2-way merges rather than a single N-way merge. There are many different ways to do the merges.

Comment: indeed, with modern hard drive cache sizes (multiple MB) sequential vs random access time wouldn't matter much.

Comment: If you know the data contained a relatively high number of repeats you could store key value pairs with merge sort combining equal keys (a key would be one of the integer values) and summing their values (count of integer appearance).

Comment: @gradbot: A worthwhile optimization if you're not concerned with the cost of a sequential search of the array each time. If there is no read buffering, then it would definitely be a worthwhile optimization because every hit would save a seek, and one seek would take the same time as many searches.

Answer (score 3):

Open 2<sup>32</sup> temporary files, one for every integer. Read sequentially through the log file once. Whenever reading integer *n*, write '1' to the temp file number *n*. Then produce the histogram by going through all the temp files. Every integer is read into memory only once, so it's O(n) algorithm.

Comment: Yeah, O(n) with a *really big* constant!

Comment: Yes LOL I want to see the OS that can have all the files open :) the answer was a joke, I think the problem wasn't well posed :)

Comment: It's a joke, but it answers the question as posed, in O(n).  It was the "answer" I'd have given, expecting them to then reword "no limit" to some reasonable number.

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep in memory 2000 int = size of
   the buffer
2. No limit for files for read / write
   = each number count will be stored in one file.
3. Numbers of 32 bits length = Each
   file is one number and the file name
   is the 32bit that represents the
   integer ( integer value can be used
   as well )
4. Show histogram (means no order is
   needed )

pseudo code:

```
count = 2000
HashMap<number, number> = new 

code:readbuffer
while count != 0 
read NextNumber
if HashMap.HasKey NextNumber then HashMap[NextNumber]++
else HashMap[NextNumber]=1
count --;
end while 

code:flushbuffer
foreach Key in HashMap 
 if exists FileName Key.ToBinnary 
  FileValue += HashMap[HashKey]
 else WriteNewFile FileName=Key.toBinnay; SetValue = 1
end foreach


code: histogram
each file name is the number;
each file value is the count.
```

Costs:  readbuffer

Sequencial number read = 2M (M = Million )

Map.HasKey = (search for the key in 2000 record, worst case the number is not there, SUMMARY( ∑2000)x2M )

SetValue on Map same cost as above

Total: (2M)+(2Mx∑2000)x2

Costs: flushbuffer
File.exists 2M

Costs: histogram
2M

Total = 6M + 4Mx∑2000

Comment: What happens if the file contains 3,000 values that are repeated? That is, the file's contents is `1,2,3,...3000,1,2,3,3000,etc.` You will end up reading each temporary file more than 300 times.

Comment: Oh god, you want to create up to 2^32 files? I don't think this is a winning answer.

Comment: @Jim Mischel yep but not a big deal as you are reading 2^32 numbers with a buffer of just 2000 values. And that's is not the worst case. the worst would be each number apear once.

Comment: @Nick Johnson, that's what everybody proposed here and actually the only possible response. There is just one other way to make it faster. Organise file names in a binary tree (like proposed below). that would make it faster to generate the histogram.

Comment: It's far from the only possible answer - see @Jim's much saner external sort for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a file based B-tree.

File names are GUIDs.

File content is:
number-seen
count
left-node-file
right-node-file

After one pass, the complexity can be derived from that of a B-tree.

And your historgram is implicit in the structure.